# React Native Helper Functional Component with ability to use Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am writing a helper component in React Native. The problem is it does not allow me to use hooks in it.

[image]

I have seen some threads where people have suggested to use class instead of functional components. But Classes also does not allow use of Hooks.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; 
import * as Constants from '../config/Constants';  
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setUser } from '../store/slices/userSlice';
import axios from 'axios';

// import { Container } from './styles';

const UserHelper = async () => {

    // const { colors }            = useTheme();
    // const [user, setLocalUser]  = useState(); 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
    const [token, setToken]     = useState();
    const user                  = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    
    // ======= my await function here which returns a dataset

    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://MY_ENDPOINT.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/",
      API_GATEWAY_POST_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE,
      { headers }
    );

    return response;
    
};

export default UserHelper;
```

So how can I define a RN helper Class or Functional Component with several functions inside it have ability to use hooks.

Comment: How can you say "The problem is it does not allow me to use hooks in it"?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi when I try to access the helper function it throws a warning saying you can only use hooks inside a RN component.

Comment: Exactly, if you use your UserHelper has a component you can use hooks. If you are using UserHelper has a function helper, it's better to convert it as a custom hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

In your UserHelper file export functions as a hooks like this.

**Example:**

**First Custom Hook**

```
export const fetchData = () => {
   // const { colors }            = useTheme();
    // const [user, setLocalUser]  = useState(); 
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
    const [token, setToken]     = useState();
    const user                  = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    
    // ======= my await function here which returns a dataset

    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://MY_ENDPOINT.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/",
      API_GATEWAY_POST_PAYLOAD_TEMPLATE,
      { headers }
    );

    return response;
};
```

**Second Custom Hook**

```
export const fetchData2 = () => {
   ... your function
};
```

**Usage:**

```
UserHelper.fetchData()
UserHelper.fetchData2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken advice from @Francesco Clementi and created a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and it worked like a charm. Thanks Francesco